# blob storage of image type

Tags: c#

I would like to retrieve an image saved as a blobtyped data in a database. How can I get it and save it into an Image/Bitmap object ?

Comment: Check this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9652634/c-sharp-reading-blob-from-sql-server-and-display-to-picture-box

Comment: What database? SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
{
    conn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT BlobFieldName FROM Table ...", conn);
    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    {
        if (reader.Read())
        {
            byte[] bytes = reader["BlobFieldName"] as byte[];

            using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(...))
            {
                stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                stream.Flush();
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I'd start with. Of course, error checking is missing here and I don't guarantee this to compile instantly :-)